# How do I delay a jQuery animation until after others finish?

Tags: jquery

I have a function that does some fairly extensive DOM manipulation, and I want to show a "Loading..." spinner while the function runs:

```
function showFoos() {
  $('#spinner').show();
  bigHairyDOMManipulation();
  $('#spinner').hide();
}

function bigHairyDOMManipulation() {
  for (var i=0; i < arrayOfFoos.length; i++){
    buildFooBox(arrayOfFoos[i], i);
  }
}

function buildFooBox(foo, index) {
  $('#foos').append(
              $('<li />').append(...)
                         .append(...)
                         ...
             );
}
```

Unfortunately, all of the `append()` calls return quickly, so even though the view isn't ready, the function is done and the spinner hides.

I can't think of a good way of chaining all of those appends together into one chain, so I can't just tack the `show()` on the front and the `hide()` on the end.

Is there another way to force the `hide()` call to wait for all the other manipulation to occur?

Comment: You could set a timeout which checks if "everything is ready" before calling to hide/show all the associated elements.

Comment: Sorry, what does this have to do with animation?

Comment: From experience, doing many appends is way slower than building a string with html inside and appending it all at once.

Comment: @Crescent Fresh: The `show()` and `hide()` calls are animations, are they not?

Comment: read http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/fastest-way-to-build-an-html-string/. Dont append inside each loop!!

Answer (score 2):

Having tons of appends and dom manipulation is a very bad idea. It will cause the browser to redraw multiple times in a row which is what slows things down. It looks like you are creating a whole bunch of new elements.

Read [43,439 reasons to use append() correctly](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly) to help you understand how to do what you need to with out going crazy with the appends

Answer (score 1):

You could append a script as the last action. Ugly, but from the description of the problem, firing an event won't work.

Comment: This is a nasty hack, but it's ingenious! I'll use it if nothing else works.

Comment: I'm curious why the call to `bigHairyDOMManipulation` is returning so quickly. From what I see in the jQuery source, `append` should be synchronous. Also, I second Alex's comment above about rewriting to decrease the number of `append` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the 'bigHairyDOMManipulation' and 'hide' calls on a callback for the show animation.

```
 function showFoos() {
    $('#spinner').show(function(){
       bigHairyDOMManipulation();
       $('#spinner').hide();
    });
  }
```